# Disable submit button, if All/Some input, textarea AND radio buttons are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sure someone has asked this question before and i have already seen code that works fine with input type text, but i want to know if it's possible to check if any Input, Textarea AND Radio Buttons are empty in a form, then disable the submit button.

I want to make sure the user fills out ALL the required fields in the form, which include textarea, text and radio buttons. Is there any way i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using too many input fields i'd recommend something as follow:

```
    <form id="myFormId">
        <input type="text" name="d1" class="dat" placeholder="test">
        <input type="text" name="d2" class="dat" placeholder="testie">
        <textarea id="textareaARE"></textarea>
        <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
        <input type="radio" name="Rad" value="test">
        <input type="radio" name="cad" value="tstt">
        <input type="text" name="d3" class="dat" placeholder="testie">
        <input type="text" name="d4" class="dat" placeholder="testie">
        <input type="text" name="d5" class="dat" placeholder="testie">
        <input type="text" name="d6" class="dat" placeholder="testie">
        <input type="text" name="d7" class="dat" placeholder="testie">
        <input type="text" name="d8" class="dat" placeholder="testie">
        <input type="text" name="d9" class="dat" placeholder="testie">
        <button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
   </form>

    function checkInputFields() {

    $('#submit').on('click', function() {

         let input = 0;
         let radio = 0;
         let text = 0;

        $('#myFormId input[type="text"]').each(function(key, inputField){
            if($(inputField).val() === '') {
               //do nothing, or exit script early, whatever floats your boat
             } else {
                 input++;
                if (input === $('#myFormId input[type="text"]').length) {
                     input = true;
                }
             }
         });
        $('#myFormId input[type="radio"]').each(function(key, inputButton){
             if(!$(inputButton).is(':checked')) {
                //do nothing, or exit script early, whatever floats your boat
                    } else {
                        radio++;
                        if (radio === $('#myFormId input[type="radio"]').length) {
                            radio = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
                $('#myFormId textarea').each(function(index, textAr) {
                    if ($(textAr).val() === '') {
                        //do nothing, or exit script early, whatever floats your boat           
                    } else {
                        text++;
                        if (text === $('#myFormId textarea').length) {
                            text = true;
                        }
                    }
                });

                console.log(input, radio, text);

                if (input === true && radio === true && text === true) {
                    $('#submit').attr('type', 'submit');
                    $('#submit').click();
                } else {
                    console.log('You forgot to fill out every required field my man.');
                }
            });

    }

//document.read(function(){});
$(function() {
  checkInputFields();
});
```

The reason I am saying: "If you aren't using too many input fields" is because your code will loop through all the elements in the `form` and then goes through every `input` or `textarea`. If these numbers were to be huge it could have performance issues (but that would probably mean you're doing something wrong).

EDIT: I made it such way that you do not need the submit button to become disabled. The moment your user clicks on it, it will either redirect the user (if everything is filled out correctly) or keep the user on the same page, in which you can decide what kind of error you would like to throw.

EDIT: I made a mistake, in which it would always result to `true` if the last value of an input field were to be inserted. I fixed it.

Comment: i have a lot of fields with child elements. This seemed to work, but after clicking on two radio buttons, the submit button enabled. The remaining 60 odd fields were empty

Comment: @tmzafar Try it again please. I changed the code a bit (took out the listener for everyone their sake) and expanded the script a bit more for textareas. Do keep in mind though, that using a type=radio with the same name will result to false. Since you can only accept one radio button which shares the same name. Having multiple with different names however IS possible :)

Comment: Perfect! That worked! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible (the way of do this will depends on the framework you're using, so I recommend to read the docs).

One way is binding the value of your fields, and check if these values are empty (as I said, the way of doing this will depend on the framework).

Doing with the old and good Jquery:

```html
<form id="sign-in">
    <div class='input-group'>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='input-group'>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class='submit-btn'>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Sign in" disabled="disabled">Sign in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And, after doing your form, just listen to your inputs, checking if the user typed something in:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.input-group input').on('keyup', function() {
    var is_empty = false;

    $('.input-group input').each(function() {
      is_empty = $(this).val().length == 0;
    });

    is_empty ? $('.submit-btn button').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    :
      $('.submit-btn button').attr('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

Since `onkeyup` event is dispatched when the users type something and stop, you can listen to this action. If `is_empty` equals `true` your input fields continue disabled, else not.

Check this fiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/s4bjqer5/

Comment: $('.input-group input') selectors and then the loop on the same selectors is inefficient, and ternary could be placed in attr vs outside, just sayin

Comment: this somehow only works with input and textarea not with radio buttons